# Finding $h(n)$ such that $h(n)/f(n) \rightarrow \infty$ and $h(n)/g(n) \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose we have a function $f(n) = n^a$ for some fixed $a>0$ and another function $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(n) \rightarrow \infty$ such that $g(n)/f(n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I.e. $g$ grows at a faster rate than $f$.

I want to prove that there always exist a function $h : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(n)/f(n) \rightarrow \infty$ and $h(n)/g(n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

So my two questions are:

A) Is this statement correct?

B) How can I prove it?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your question. The title says $h/f$ and $h/g$, whereas the statement of the problem says $h/f$ in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, @AnuragA, I've fixed the typos!

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @uniquesolution, it's not homework. This lemma came up in relation to threshold functions in probabilistic graph theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest description of such a function (I think) is
$$
h(n) = \sqrt{f(n)g(n)}
$$
assuming $g(n)$ is always non-negative. If $g(n)$ is negative for some $n$, you need to tweak the definition of $h$ for those $n$.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks a lot!